# Python function with optional print output

Tags: python

I have function and I would like to make optional prints in function - if parameter of function output is True - do calculation and prints, if output is False, then do just a calculation.

```
def function(start, end, output=True):
    while start < end:
        start += 2
        print("start: " + start)
    print("Done")
```

Comment: What you are looking for is an [`if` statement](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements).

Answer (score 0):

```
def function(start, end, output=True):
    while start < end:
        start += 2
        if output:
            print("start: {}".format(start))
            print("print if output is true")
        print("remaining: {}".format(end - start))
    print("Done")

function(10,20, True)
function(10,20, False)
```

output:

```
start: 12
print if output is true
remaining: 8
start: 14
print if output is true
remaining: 6
start: 16
print if output is true
remaining: 4
start: 18
print if output is true
remaining: 2
start: 20
print if output is true
remaining: 0
Done

remaining: 8
remaining: 6
remaining: 4
remaining: 2
remaining: 0
Done
```